# Compiling Cython extensions without calling python setup.py or setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, cythonize

I am working with Docker containers to encapsulate deep learning experiments. When setting up  the Docker, I am running a python file which first runs `cythonize` from `Cython.Build` and then I run `gcc` on the compiled files.

Is there a possibility to use setuptools in this way? For instance https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark/blob/master/setup.py compiles CUDA and Cython extensions and then install these as a package. However, for my use case this is inconvenient.

From this script, I basically would like to run the compilation through a function like setup() without actually installing the package.

```
setup(
    name="maskrcnn_benchmark",
    version="0.1",
    author="fmassa",
    url="https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrnn-benchmark",
    description="object detection in pytorch",
    packages=find_packages(exclude=("configs", "tests",)),
    # install_requires=requirements,
    ext_modules=get_extensions(),
    cmdclass={"build_ext": torch.utils.cpp_extension.BuildExtension},
)
```

Comment: Run `python setup.py build_ext` in a `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: If the requirement is to explicitly avoid calling `setup.py` as stated in the title, you have the `--embed` option that you pass to `cython` to translate the extensions to plain C code. You can then compile them yourself.

Comment: @hoefling Yes, that would be executing the binary separately, is there no way to do this directly through python?

Comment: I suppose you can call the same function `cython` does. Smth like (untested!) `from Cython.Compiler.Main import CompilationOptions, compile; opts = CompilationOptions(embed=True); compile('path/to/file.pyx', opts)`. However, since this code is intended to be called via command line, it may not be suited for being called in a program (polluting the globals with own stuff etc).